# Lighting Tree Conditional Highlight

Tags: lightning-aura-components

lighting:tree component generates the tree structure natively.
I am looking for the ability to make a record bold, unbold based on certain conditions.
From the server-side, if I construct the HTML tag (the tags are rendered as is)
Whare are the alternatives

- DOM.InnerHtml ?
- Component.FIND

Answer (score 1):

You can't "reach in" to a component's internals and modify the elements you find there. This is a core tenant of Web Components. If you need this type of functionality, you'll have to build your own component using the SLDS blueprint for [Lightning Tree](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/trees/) or [Lightning Tree Grid](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tree-grid/).